# Require.js and twitter-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs

I have implemented a require.js-scipt to put twitter-bootstrap in a separate module. But when I test if it works as supposed with a page containing a button that shall open a modal dialog nothing happens. I'm guessing that I must do something more to glue together the css-components with the require-module. But I don't find where I have to change. The module prints the "Loaded.."-message to the console so it seems to work so far.

My module:

```
require.config({
    paths : {
        'jquery' : ['extdep/jquery-1-8-3'],
        'bootstrap-modal' : ['extdep/twitter-bootstrap/js/bootstrap-modal']
    },
    shim : {
        'bootstrap-modal' : ['jquery']
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'bootstrap-modal'],
     function($){
         console.log("Loaded :)");    
         return {};
     }
);
```

Div that implements the modal dialog and script-tag to module.

```
    <div class="container">
                <h2>Example of creating Modals with Twitter Bootstrap</h2>
                <div id="example" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                        <h3>This is a Modal Heading</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
                        <p>You can add some text here.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a> <a href="#"
                            class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#example"
                        class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Launch demo modal</a>
                </p>
            </div>

<script data-main="main" 
            src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.4/require.min.js" />
```

Do you have any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: I don't think your paths are meant to be surrounded by []

Comment: @LukeVella, that doesn't make any difference as far as I can see.

Comment: I'm experiencing similar issue. When loading bootstrap as require module my data attributes are not parsed at all.

Comment: and yes, your paths shouldn't be defined as arrays but regardless it doesnt make a difference

Answer (score 2):

Your shim is wrong. And Shouldn't you also have a shim for jQuery itself? Or are you using a version that is built to work with Require.js?

```
shim : {
    'jquery':{
        exports: 'jQuery'
    },
    'bootstrap-modal': {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: 'jQuery.fn.modal'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*I think* you need `data-parent="example"` on this line.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#example" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Launch demo modal</a>
```

But I'm not 100%. You should make a jsfiddle so we can play with it.